# Google map does not render on IE11 (only with DevTools)

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a strange situation when the page like [this one](http://www.sar.fr/fr/international/international) have a Google Map that does not render when first opened in IE(11).
In other "normal" browsers there is no such a problem.

However when I try to identify the problem in IE11 opening the `F12 Developer Tools`, the map suddenly appears.... !??

IE warns

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For
>   more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

but I am not sure if the problem is in caching here....

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs if the server sends a "Cache-control:no-store" header or sends a "Cache-control:no-cache" header.

Try clearing your cache

Comment: The problem is right. Clearing the cache helps, but how to avoid it, in order that IE opens the map at the very first rendering, and not only after the cache clearing...